# GTK GUI: pygtk vs vala

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, vala

I am working on cloud storage project and want to build GTK client for it. Possible choices found are `pygtk/glade` and `vala`. For the moment I am not familiar neither with `pygtk` nor with `vala`. Some googling showed that `vala` is quite a good choice. But I know python and completely new to `vala`. So I am looking for very strong arguments for `vala` in order to decide whether to use it or not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try both out, pick the one you like best. FWIW, I believe `pygtk` is a very important and widely used binding, from which I'm assuming it shouldn't have any major deficiencies, so I'd stick with Python in your case.

Comment: I believe that `pygtk` should work too. Client will be quite simple. It will be basically config editor so possible performance improvment or anything else that comes with `vala` may not worth spent time.

Comment: In any case don't use PyGTK - it is officially dying out and only works with GTK 2.0. If you decide to go for Python, use PyGTK's successor, PyGObject, which works with GTK 3.

Comment: Also, note that you can use Glade with both Python and Vala.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Under `pygtk` I really mean `python+gtk`. But thanks for correction anyway.

Comment: If you want to have fun, you can also use both languages, for example: creating Vala libs for components where performance is important, generate `typelibs` of that libs and load the libs with Python. There is a good demonstration of this right here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QrGmA_RR4E

Answer (score 2):

A lot of Gnome apps are currently being rewritten in vala. This gives better performance and a better integration with the gtk libraries.

I personally think the language is pretty good, for a compiled language, but no doubt it is not as powerful or widely used as python.

If you are building an open source app (or something other people are going to maintain), you might want to go with the language that more people use. However there are also many benefits on being on the new, officially pushed wagon, like integration and a "coolness" factor.

Comment: I'm far more familiar with Python than Vala, but from what I understand Vala usually tackles the interface and C/C++ handles most of the logic in modern open source Vala/GTK programs.